# DataBind GridView in modal dialog on button click

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a problem with binding data in modal dialog.
I have a similar ascx file

```
<asp:Panel ID="ModalDialog" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ResultGridTest" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ShowHeader="true" Width="100%" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ResultGridTest" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Modal dialog is opened as jquery dialog

```
$j("#ModalDialog").dialog("open");
```

The problem is that when I am trying to bind data to ResultGridTest in handling method which is firing on passed value from another control, ResultGridHas has no any visible data.
My handling method:

```
protected void GridViewControl_DataBindGridView(object sender, PassSelectedValuesEventArgs<Model> e)
{
    ResultGridTest.DataSource = e.SelectedItems;
    ResultGridTest.DataBind();
}
```

Do you have any idea how to bind data after event occurs in my modal dialog?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your UpdatePanel has a **UpdateMode** as Conditional. You need to udpate it manually. add UpdatePanel.Update(); to your method after DataBind().

Comment: Still does not work, ChildrenAsTriggers should cause the same effect as manually fired Update method on UpdatePanel

Comment: ChildrenAsTriggers works with immediate child element. Which is the immediate child element of UpdatePanel according to you? I am confused between considering ContentTemplate or not in this?

Comment: ResultGridTest is a child control, what is defined in triggerpostback. If i am wrong, dont blame me, i am noob in asp net web forms

Comment: Could you please try to use triggers with UpdateMode = "Always" ? Or manual updating of UpdatePanel without using triggers?